# Is it possible to return a DataSet as a string from a WCF to a Windows Form?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

**EDIT:**
I replaced the old code with new code that worked! I ended up using the SqlDataReader and it worked perfectly!

**OLD POST:**
*I have 2 solutions in VS2010, the first is a WCF service, and the second is a test client application. Up until now, most of the operation contracts on the WCF have been either DataSet type, bool type, or string type. With the DataSet operations, I normally retrieve for display in my testClient app. For bool and string, I insert data into my DB.*

*Where I'm getting stuck is that I'm trying to use a single operation in the interface that will run a sql statement based on certain factors coming from the testClient app. So I basically want to pass 2 values from my app to the service, which will use them in the sql statement, and then return the value it gets from the DB back to the testClient app. Below is what I have so far, I have tried all sorts of ways but the closest I have come to it is returning either a message into a textbox that reads "Table" or "System.Data.DataSet", it should be returning a URL from the DB.*

**Service.cs:**

```
public string GetFileURL(DeviceDetails deviceInfo)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=vurdevice;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT FileURL FROM VR_Image WHERE IMEINo = @IMEINo AND FileName = @FileName", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IMEINo", deviceInfo.IMEINo);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", deviceInfo.FileName);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            deviceInfo.FileURL = reader.GetString(0);
        }
        con.Close();
        return deviceInfo.FileURL;
    }
```

**IService.cs:**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    string InsertDetails(DeviceDetails deviceInfo);

    [OperationContract]
    DataSet GetCarrierList();

    [OperationContract]
    DataSet GetStorageList();

    [OperationContract]
    DataSet GetMainTable();

    [OperationContract]
    bool DeleteDetails(DeviceDetails deviceInfo);

    [OperationContract]
    DataSet GetStatTable();

    [OperationContract]
    DataSet GetFileURL(DeviceDetails deviceInfo);
}

[DataContract]
public class DeviceDetails
{
    string imeiNo;
    string fileName;
    string fileURL;
    string uploader;
    string carrierID;
    string storageName;
    int fileSize;
    DateTime createDate;
    string deleteID;
    DateTime deleteDate;
    string defectCode;
    string modelCode;
    string updateStatus;

    [DataMember]
    public string IMEINo
    {
        get { return imeiNo; }
        set { imeiNo = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string FileName
    {
        get { return fileName; }
        set { fileName = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string FileURL
    {
        get { return fileURL; }
        set { fileURL = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Uploader
    {
        get { return uploader; }
        set { uploader = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string CarrierID
    {
        get { return carrierID; }
        set { carrierID = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string StorageName
    {
        get { return storageName; }
        set { storageName = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int FileSize
    {
        get { return fileSize; }
        set { fileSize = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime CreateDate
    {
        get { return createDate; }
        set { createDate = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string DeleteID
    {
        get { return deleteID; }
        set { deleteID = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime DeleteDate
    {
        get { return deleteDate; }
        set { deleteDate = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string DefectCode
    {
        get { return defectCode; }
        set { defectCode = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string ModelCode
    {
        get { return modelCode; }
        set { modelCode = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string UpdateStatus
    {
        get { return updateStatus; }
        set { updateStatus = value; }
    }
}
```

Later on in my testClient app, I have a WinForm with this.....

**Show.cs**

```
public partial class ShowImage : Form
{
    vurServiceReference.Service1Client obj = new vurServiceReference.Service1Client();
    private string strIMEI, strFile;
    public ShowImage(string strIMEI, string strFile)
    {
        this.strIMEI = strIMEI;
        this.strFile = strFile;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ShowImage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strFileURL = this.GetFileURL();

        if (strFileURL.Equals(""))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No image available");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            sampleBox.Text = strFileURL;
        }
    }

    private string GetFileURL()
    {
        vurServiceReference.DeviceDetails objdetail = new vurServiceReference.DeviceDetails();
        string url;

        objdetail.IMEINo = strIMEI;
        objdetail.FileName = strFile;
        url = obj.GetFileURL(objdetail);
        return url;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you just need a single piece of data, why are you using a `DataSet`?  That is way overkill, IMO - and it's not good SOA practice either.  Best practice would be to return a simple type value (i.e,. `int`, `string`, etc) or a custom complex type (i.e., a `DataContract`-decorated class) that can be serialized.

Comment: @Tim, Thanks for the advice. I'm a complete noob to programming and I have a mentor who hates me asking questions for clarification. So everything I'm doing, I'm learning on my own through books and some video online. I ended up using SqlDataReader and had success.